# Nested query with Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have this relationship in my Location model:

```
public function special_users() {
    return $this->users()
    ->where('type_id', '=', '2')
    ->orWhere('type_id', '=', 'null');
}
```

But what I want are Users where type_id = 2 and the Users where type_id = null only if there is no User for this Location where type_id = 2.

Is this possible?

Comment: Still lookin for a solution . . .

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about DBMS's; not about Laravel.

Usually these type of queries are executed by Querying for type_id = 2. If no records are found, simply fire a second query where you fetch type_id = 0.

Comment: Thanks R.  Your suggestion doesn't work because there will be records found for Users where their type_id = 2.  I need to find Users for type_id = 0 (null) ONLY if none for that particular User with a type_id = 2 are found.
I'm sure it's because I didn't explain the problem properly.  No worries and thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I devised a solution.  So for anyone having a similar problem, here it is.  I'm sure it could be executed less costly and would love to be shown how so but for now, enjoy.

```php
class Location extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'locations';

    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User')->withTimestamps()->withPivot(['type_id']);
    }

    public function chef_users() {
        return $this->users()->where('type_id', '2');
    }
}

class DishController extends BaseController {
    $chef_locations = Location::with('chef_users')->get();
    foreach ($chef_locations as $cl) {
        foreach ($cl->chef_users as $cu) {
            $chef_user_ids[] = $cu->id;
        }
    }

    $locations = Location::with(
        array('users' => function($lu_query) use($chef_user_ids) {
            $lu_query->where('type_id', '2');
            $lu_query->orWhere(function($nested_query) use($chef_user_ids) {
                $nested_query->whereNull('type_id');
                $nested_query->whereNotIn('user_id', $chef_user_ids);
            });
        })
    )
}
```